# Show that vectors is basis for $P^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $ β = \{ 1, 2t, −2 + 4t^2, −12t + 8t^3 \} $ is a basis for $ P^3[ \Bbb{R}]. $

Is the following calculation correct?

Checking if linearly independent: $$ \displaylines{
c_1\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} +c_2\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
2 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + c_3 \begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
0 \\
4 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + c_4 \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-12 \\
0 \\
8
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
} 
$$
$$  \displaylines{
 \begin{bmatrix}
c_1 - 2c_3 = 0 \\
2c_2 - 12c_4 = 0  \\
4c_3 = 0 \\
8c_4 = 0
\end{bmatrix}.
}$$
$c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = c_4 = 0.$ Therefore, it is linearly independent.
$$ \displaylines{} $$
Checking whether it generates $P^3 \Bbb{R}$:

$$ \displaylines{
 \begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y\\
w\\
z
\end{bmatrix} = c_1\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} +c_2\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
2 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + c_3 \begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
0 \\
4 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + c_4 \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-12 \\
0 \\
8
\end{bmatrix}
} $$

$$ \displaylines{
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 - 2c_3 = x \\
2c_2 - 12c_4 = y  \\
4c_3 = w \\
8c_4 = z
\end{bmatrix}. 
}$$

$$ \displaylines{
c_1 = x \\
c_2 = \frac{3z+2y+w}{4} \\
c_3 = \frac{w}{4} \\
c_4 = \frac{z}{8}.
}$$
With these calculations do I prove that it is basis of $P^3$?

Comment: Yes. Actually one of them suffices as we know the dimension of the space.

Comment: So just saying the dimension is N + 1 and it's linear independent would be enough?

Comment: Well, we have $4$ vectors that are linear independent / generator system in a $4$ dimensional vector space.